# How add Check-in Policy in Process Template

Tags: tfs

I'm Installed Power Tools for TFS  on developer  machine, I had new Check-in Policy - "ChangesetComments".

How to add this Check-in Policy in Process Template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click on your Team Project in Team Explorer & select "Team Project Settings" > "Source Control...".
 Go to Tab "Check-in Policy" and press "Add..". You should find it there and select it.

Comment: How automate that process for new projects?

Comment: @maslbl4 You should be able to write a plugin and hook into the project create event using the bissubscribe tool. `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010\Tools>BisSubscribe.exe /collection http://{url}/{collection} /eventType ProjectCreatedEvent /deliveryType {type}` I think one of the delivery types you can specify is to a custom web service, from which you'll write code using the TFS API to add your check in policy template. This is all conjecture but should do the job.

Comment: Hmm, there doesn't seem to exist a method to include a check-in policy in a Process Template. See here for a reference http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/hu-HU/tfsprocess/thread/cefb9c5f-219d-460f-87cd-d3ec9c02d58c. This post also presents with an alternative (a TFS-API console app that adds the checkin policy after the new TeamProject has been created) - not quite satisfactory, still better than nothing.